# using batch file to get active members of an AD group

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I am trying to create a batch file to run and check what members of an AD are active (have logged in within the last 90 days) I have begun but am stuck at a portion when trying to read the output and have that search each user...

batch code:

```
@echo off
cls
set "Output=C:\GroupMembersOut\test.txt"
net group ToolUsers /domain >> "%Output%"
timeout /t 10
```

What I get back in the text file is this:

```
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain ***.com.

Group name     **************
Comment        ******** ***********

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*********                *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
*******                  *******                  *******                  
********                 ********                 ********                 
The command completed successfully.
```

***As a note per the comments, the first UserID is my admin ID which is longer than 7 characters, most Login IDs are 7 characters and the contractors have an 8 character length ***

Which is what I want, but now I need a way to search each user in a `net user %user% /domain` type way so I can begin the next step of stripping the name of the user and the last login. thanks for any advice, as a side note if anyone can help I would also like to add an input box for the ADgroup (in this case ToolUsers) so I can use the tool in a better way other than editing the bat everytime I want to search a new group. but thats just a side thing and not required.

Comment: I don't often say this but you would be better of using Powershell to do this.

Comment: I tried using powershell but when I go to `import-module activedirectory` i get an error that its not a valid module

Comment: You probably need to install the PowerShell Active Directory module, [Windows 10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/02/26/install-the-active-directory-powershell-module-on-windows-10/) / [Windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rkramesh/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7/).

Comment: here's the fun part... my job has us super locked down so we can install anything on our local machines...

Comment: If you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50628092/edit) to include the text file content properly formatted, (as code), we may be able to find a workaround. _Note that the output you've provided is from the console not the text file._ Also if you change `set Output=C:\GroupMembersOut\test.txt` to `set "Output=C:\GroupMembersOut\test.txt"` and `start cmd.exe /k "net group ToolUsers /domain >> %Output%"` to `net group ToolUsers /domain>"%Output%"` it would certainly be a script improvement, which you could then update within that same question edit.

Comment: actually that output is copied from the txt file not the console, I only edited the info in it before i pasted (ie: domain, ADgroup name and userIDs) because, well, security. but its that same exact format in the txt file.

Comment: Are you sure that the output is not in fixed width columns, the output you're showing shows as partially non-fixed and some rows contain more users than others. I'd prefer that you still improved the code as I've suggested, then ran it to produce the `test.txt` file again. If you feel the need to edit the information, _which doesn't reveal any secure information at all_, just replace individual non whitespace characters with the same number, type and format of characters_. It is extremely important that we can exactly replicate the output, in order to attempt any workaround.

Comment: Sorry, but at my company I could get fired for publicly listing our domain, ADGroup names and user login IDs. But yes the frank one is in error and I will adjust, I did run the code edits and returned the same results in the same format. But I will place the EXACT list with things * out so as not to shorten or adjust anything.